# Loop delete rows based on Count and * of days

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to delete rows in SQLite based on Count and * of days.

Instead of writing multiple SQL commands like this:

```sql
DELETE * FROM result WHERE Count = 1 AND ("min(_time)" < strftime('%s','now', '-7 day'));
DELETE * FROM result WHERE Count = 2 AND ("min(_time)" < strftime('%s','now', '-14 day'))
DELETE * FROM result WHERE Count = 3 AND ("min(_time)" < strftime('%s','now', '-28 day'));
```

and so on...

I am trying to find a way to use for loop where it increments Count and the * days

I tried this:

```
data = c1.execute('''SELECT * FROM result;''')

for row in data:
    Count = row[1]
    days = row[7]
    c1.execute('''DELETE * FROM result WHERE Count = ? AND ("min(_time)" < strftime('%s','now', '-? day'));''', (Count, days))
```

I am getting a `IndexError: tuple index out of range` under `days = row[7]`.

I looked up the [error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) and changed the number see if it would fix it, still indexerror.

Sample data of the result table looks like this: "select * from result;" Columns exported from Splunk: src_ip, 'min(_time)', Count

```
183.78.180.27|1542266993|1
185.189.150.42|1542246169|1
185.189.150.61|1542271436|1
2002:8672:d515::8672:d515|1537536602|3
150.135.165.114|1537288499|3
```

Am I getting the concept for the script correct? Any suggestions on the indexerror? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're assigning count the same thing every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand your second example code -- it does a SELECT and then another SELECT in a loop -- it never tries to DELETE, which is what you said you want.

Comment: Please fix [`cursor.fetchall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) as it does not receive parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterizing the entire interval date, `'-7 day'`, `'-14 day'`, ... since qmark placeholders should not be quoted. Then, pass the built string into `.execute()` call:

```
delete_sql = '''DELETE FROM result 
                WHERE [Count] = ? 
                AND ("min(_time)" < strftime('%s', 'now', ?));
             '''

data = c1.execute("SELECT * FROM ...")

for i in data.fetchall():
    Count = i[0]
    days = '-{} day'.format(i[7])

    c1.execute(delete_sql, (Count, days))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! So the Count gets incremented 0,1, 2, 3,... and so on, as well with days? Sorry I'm new with python :/   the code outputs an 'IndexError: tuple index out of range' at 'days = '-{} day'.format(row[7])' I am looking for a solution, appreciate any help!

Comment: *Count* does not increment but uses what ever is the first column in your `SELECT * FROM ...` query and similarly the day value will derive from 8th column of same query. Please post a few rows of this result to see what loop fetches.

Comment: appreciate the response! I work part time at university so my response can be late. Ok, I am getting an index error therefore could not get a result from the script. my select statement is `"SELECT * FROM result;"` I also need to increment Count so I put `Count = i[1]`. I am trying to delete rows based on Count and days like stated in the first commands I posted in the question. still looking into this. I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Please edit your post with sample data of *result* table for a [MCVE].

Comment: @acb452: You have to use `Count = i[2]` and `days = '-{} day'.format(i[1])`

Comment: @stovfl The reason I have `Count = i[1]` is because I want to increment Count from 1,2,3,... and `days = '-{} day'.format(i[7])` to increment every by 7,14,28,... days. I tried your example it returned `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.`

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: I am trying to find a way to use for loop where it increments Count and the * days

Increment `Count` and `days`:

```
    day = -7        
    for count in range(1, 4):
        print("WHERE Count = {} AND '{} day')".format(count, day))
        day = day * 2
```

> **Output**:
>   **Note**: This is **not** ready to use for a SQL statement!
>
> ```
> WHERE Count = 1 AND '-7 day')
> WHERE Count = 2 AND '-14 day')
> WHERE Count = 3 AND '-28 day')
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3***